# angular : ng-controller is not working?

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, controller

When I use `ng-controller=""`, it isn't working.

I get this error in my web browser console. Could anyone help to fix this?

[image: [1]: https://]

This is my html code I use for testing. When I remove ng-controller="", angular is working but I can't use ng-controller="" for my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html ng-app>
 <head>
  <title>APP</title>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <!-- Optional theme -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="controllers/controller.js">
 </script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>

 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

  <h1>Users</h1>

  <table class="table">
   <thead>
   <tr>
   <td>Name</td>
   <td>Email</td>
   <td>ID</td>
   </tr>
   </thead>
  </table>
  </div>

  <input ng-model="test">
  {{test}}



 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide some examples of your controllers? maybe also your page html to see if you are missing something else? Like `ng-app`?

Comment: I uploaded my sample html page. This is my sample controller.                       function AppCtrl(){
 console.log("Hello from controller")
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your ng-controller="AppCtrl" on the body because you are using ng-model outside the scope of the controller.